# pytesseract OCR - Extract the font-size from the images

Tags: font-size, python-tesseract

I have extracted text from images using Pytesseract OCR ( A python Wrapper of Tesseract). Now i want to find the approximate Font size used in the input image. I searched over the internet and found that there was previously a function "WordFontAttributes" but it is no more available. Any alternate to this please